# Error reading data into Spark using spraklyr::spark_read_csv

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm running Spark in 'standalone' mode on a local machine in Docker containers. I have a master and two workers, each is running in its own Docker container. In each of the containers the path `/opt/spark-data` is mapped to the same local directory on the host.

I'm connecting to the Spark master from `R` using `sparklyr`, and I can do a few things, for example, loading data into Spark using `sparklyr::copy_to`.

However, I cannot get `sparklyr::spark_read_csv` to work. The data I'm trying to load is in the local directory that is mapped in the containers. When attaching to the running containers I can see that the file I'm trying to load does exist in each of the 3 containers, in the local (to the container) path `/opt/spark-data`.

This is an example for the code I'm using:

```
xx_csv <- spark_read_csv(
  sc,
  name = "xx1_csv",
  path = "file:///opt/spark-data/data-csv"
)
```

`data-csv` is a directory containing a single CSV file. I've also tried specifying the full path, including the file name.
When I'm calling the above code, I'm getting an exception:

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/opt/spark-data/data-csv;
```

I've also tried with different numbers of `/` in the `path` argument, but to no avail.

The documentation for `spark_read_csv` says that

> path: The path to the file. Needs to be accessible from the
> cluster. Supports the ‘"hdfs://"’, ‘"s3a://"’ and ‘"file://"’
> protocols.

My naive expectation is that if, when attaching to the container, I can see the file in the container file system, it means that it is "accessible from the cluster", so I don't understand why I'm getting the error. All the directories and files in the path are owned by rood and have read permissions by all.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

try without "file://" and with \\ if your are Windows user.